# Problem rendering powerline font in urxvt

Tags: fonts, urxvt

I downloaded some Powerline fonts and tried to set some of those in my .Xresources file but all the time urxvt can't render some fonts.

My current config is this one:

```
URxvt*font:  xft:Source\ Code\ Pro\ for\ Powerline:size=13, \ 
             xft:FontAwesome:size=6
```

This is what xfce4-terminal renders:
[image: Good]

This is what urxvt renders using the same font:
[image: Bad]

I really appreciate any kind of help and I'm sorry for my english.